# Case Insensitive default_scope :order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following test that passed under mysql (using FactoryGirl):

```
  test "order by title" do
    @library = create(:drawing_library, title: 'Accessories')
    @drawing = create(:drawing, drawing_library: @library, title: 'Test Drawing')
    create(:drawing, drawing_library: @library, title: 'z')
    create(:drawing, drawing_library: @library, title: 'm')
    create(:drawing, drawing_library: @library, title: 'b')

    str = ''
    @library.drawings.each do |dwg|
      str += dwg.title
    end

    assert_equal 'bmTest Drawingz', str
  end
```

The Drawing model is:

```
class Drawing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :drawing_library
  default_scope order: :title
  ..
end
```

Under postgresql, this test now fails with:

```
<"bmTest Drawingz"> expected but was
<"Test Drawingbmz">.
```

This appears to be because of the T in 'Test Drawing' being uppercase.  If I change it to 'test Drawing', the test passes.

Is there a way to make `default_scope order` case insensitive?

Comment: You might also want to pay attention to collation settings and statement options. Some collations will only use case as a tie-breaker if values are otherwise identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the default scope to order by the lower case title:

```
default_scope order: 'lower(title)'
```

Or, if you like yelling, you could use upper case instead:

```
default_scope order: 'upper(title)'
```

This should work pretty much the same regardless of which database you're using or what configuration settings it has (unless of course your database is configured to use interesting collation rules).

You might want to include the table name if you're expecting this default scope to be involved in joins.

Comment: Would that greatly affect performance to add a function like that?

Comment: @croceldon: It wouldn't come for free but I don't think it would have a great impact; unless you're doing `M.all` all the time but you have bigger problems than `order by lower(title)` if you're loading whole tables all the time. Adding an index on `lower(title)` might help but you'll have to fight a bit with Rails to add an index on a computed value.